# How to convert one Tree into another Tree?

Tags: java, tree

In our project we have complex data models that are represented by Tree structures. Time to time we need to convert tree models from one model into another and back. For that, we built custom made Mappings Associations Framework which works this way (simplified):

For example, we have a Tree with root node 'a' which have node 'b' which have node 'date' in int format and we want to map to another tree with root node 'b' which has 'date' in String format. Our association with transform methods will look like this:

```
a.b.date(TransformDateToString) = b.date(TransformDateToInt)
```

This was a very simple case. Real transformations are more complex.

Just wondering if there is a way to do it better? Is there any ready to use Java library that helps to perform transformations between trees?

Comment: I know that you can do these kind of transformations in XML with XSLT. So you might be able to repurpose an XSLT processor to your needs.